# Wordpress Изменение Контента Страницы

Tags: php, wordpress

Всем привет, почитал мануал и посмотрел видео про wordpress, нашел что есть скрипты для изменения текста

```
<?php the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

и для изменения заголовка

```
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

вопрос, а что если у меня несколько заголовков на одной странице ??? 
И я хочу их всех менять но чтобы они были разные,

```
Заголовок 1 <?php the_title(); ?>

Заголовок 2 <?php the_title(); ?>
```

при подобной конструкции, одно название заголовка идет для всех заголовков.
Как сделать их разными ?

Answer (score 0):

> нашел что есть скрипты для изменения текста

Это не скрипты, а функции WordPress. Они не для изменения, а для вывода.

the_post() - устанавливает переменные поста, используется в цикле, на экран ничего не выводит.

the_title() - выводит заголовок.

the_content() - выводит тело поста.

Заголовок у поста (страницы) всегда один - это название. Если внутри тела поста нужны подзаголовки, то они выводятся тегами html `<h2>...<h6>`.

Comment: это ответ ? 
как мне сделать несколько изменяемых заголовков ?

Comment: Это ответ. В тексте поста у вас может быть любое количество заголовков, которые вы можете изменять, редактируя пост в админке.

Comment: спаибо, я знаю что "может" быть много заголовков, я спрашиваю как сделать так чтобы можно было в админке редактировать несколько заколовков ?

я прописываю всем заголовкам the_title();
захожу на страницу, а там только 1 заголовок, тем самым изменяя один заголовок , все другие заголовки изменяются также и у них одинаковые имена, мой вопрос заключался в том как сделать несколько заголовков которые можно изменить в админке, я не получил ответ

Comment: мой вопрос заключался в том как сделать несколько заголовков которые можно изменить в админке,< в вопросе этого нет. в админке несколько заголовков быть не может. Если вам нужно несколько раз в теле поста вывести один и тот же заголовок, то вы можете создать шаблон страницы, и в коде php несколько раз использовать the_title(). Ваш вопрос изначально непонятен, потому что создан без соответствия правилам. Согласно правилам, вы должны создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: 3 Заголовка на одной странице, и все 3 имеют разное значение, как сделать чтобы можно было их менять в админке ?
Вот в чем вопрос

<h1> Пример </h1>

<h1> Привет 2 </h1>

<h1> Привет 3 </h1>

Comment: если всем вместо значения присвоить the_content(); они будут иметь все одно и тоже значение, а мне нужно чтобы разное

Comment: Покажите, что вами уже сделано и что не получается. С вашим кодом и картинками из админки. Другими словами, создайте минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve